# Is there a way to avoid $this-> everywhere?

Tags: php, oop, class

I have a class with many methods and variables in PHP. Every time I need a method to call another in the same class, I have to add `$this->`. This (!) produces some badly legible source, such as:

```
$nextX = $this->calculateNextX($this->DX, $this->DY, $this->DZ);
$nextY = $this->calculateNextY($this->DX, $this->DY, $this->DZ);
$nextZ = $this->calculateNextZ($this->DX, $this->DY, $this->DZ);
$this->X = $nextX;
$this->Y = $nextY;
$this->Z = $nextZ;
```

Is there a way to avoid `$this->` everywhere?

Comment: How about having each calculate method modify the respective property?

Comment: @BoltClock Not always it will do so. Each calculate is reusable in other places. I made it already read X, Y, and Z to avoid passing more three variables.

Comment: You could create local aliases beforehand `$DX = & $this->DX;` and then use these. That doesn't shorten your code much, but avoids a few `$this->`es.

Comment: The answer is going to be slightly different for every situation. I would refactor the code you have now as simply `$this->calculateNext();` (which might use `calculateNextX` internally).

Comment: @AbhiBeckert But that doesn't remove the need for `$this->` for OO in PHP ... JavaScript, Python, and Perl are some others languages that also need an explicit "this"... it just looks extra-ugly in PHP. (Closures are orthogonal to properties and PHP is in a competition with Perl for which one is the "most ugly" ;-)

Comment: @fernacolo: Why don't you just write `$this->X = $this->calculateNextX(...);`

Comment: @Dan Because if I change `X`, then `calculateNextY` and `calculateNextZ` would yield wrong results.

Comment: Alright. Thought as you passed DX and such although they are class properties that IT didnt depend on other parameters.  Not very consitent.

Comment: PHP is an ugly language. Get used to it, and try to write your code as clean as possible within the constraints.

Comment: Mario's comment should be an answer. Depending on use scenario, it's very good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible to avoid that construct with PHP's built-in notion of OOP.

PHP, like JavaScript, Python and Perl -- but unlike Java and not always like Ruby -- *always requires an explicit receiver* -- or, `$this` for the "current instance" -- to access members. The syntax is just the form PHP happens to use to denote this construct and was likely heavily influenced by "being a late comer" to the language and having to fit it. It is also reminiscent of Perl/C syntax.

While the *location* can be altered or the number of sites may be reducible, at the end of the day, that *is* the method of accessing members.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in each method

```
extract(get_object_vars($this));
```

Although that would only let you get variables, not methods, nor static properties. And they wouldn't be references, so only useful for reading.

Comment: You saved me a php rant.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to something else

```
$a = $this;
$a->stuff();
```

Even in C++ I prefer to use `this` though for clarity that you are acting on a class member.  It's not optional in PHP though.